# About audio and video plugins

Tags: system-installation

I install ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS.
I tried command as,

$ sudo apt-get install restricted-extras

but it gives error as,

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package restricted-extras

How can I solve this error?

Answer (score 1):

The correct package name is `ubuntu-restricted-extras` (or `xubuntu-restricted-extras` or `lubuntu-restricted-extras` for Xubuntu and Lubuntu respectively).